# PsExec run registry file remotely. disabling USB on a PC

Tags: powershell, registry, psexec

I am trying to block USB mass Storage device on a PC and I want to do it remotely using powershell.

```
$computer = 'hostname';
$username = 'hostname_username';
$password = 'password';
$usb      = '//remote/installer/lockRemovableStorageDevices.reg';

$usb_command = "psExec -i -d -c -f -s \\$computer -u $computer\$username -p $password `"$usb`"";

Write-Output "Disabling USB in $computer.";

Invoke-Expression $usb_command;
```

upon running this code, I got this error.

```
PsExec could not start lockRemovableStorageDevices.reg on computer_name:
```

Thanks,

Comment: Hint: A .reg file is not an executable.

Comment: is there any way to do that using powershell?

Comment: I would recommend updating the registry using group policy rather than hitting individual machines with psexec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this "better" in PowerShell. You can use the remote Registry provider and WMI access to registry to manipulate the remote registry directly. Or, use  Invoke-Command to invoke a command on the remote machine.

If you do want to stick with psExec, you will have to import the .reg file.
Try this in your script:

```
$usb = 'regedit /s //remote/installer/lockRemovableStorageDevices.reg'
```